# HTML5 AudioPlayer Event Action 'Ended' is being call more than One time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, audio-player

I am working with HTML5 Audio Player. I am implementing playlist. I am using 'ended' event action to play the next audio media file. But, At the end of media file, 'ended' event is fired more than one time. (As the message I log appears more then one time.)

This is my Event Listener:

```
    //Event Listener
function addPlayerListener() {
    console.log("Recording Index: "+combinedSessionIndex);

    var audio = document.getElementById("playarea");
    audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {

        sessionsToPlay = $("#audio_files").val().split(',');

        console.log ("In Recording End Event Listener...!!!"+combinedSessionIndex);
        //It Shows Length '1' not '0'
        if (sessionsToPlay.length == 1) {
            console.log("Returned Due to Session To Play length..!!!")
            return;
        }

        //As CombinedSessionIndex Starts with 1
        if (combinedSessionIndex == sessionsToPlay.length) {
            console.log("Returned Due to All Session To Play Got Finish..!!!")
            $("#audio_files").val("");
            sessionsToPlay = [];
            combinedSessionIndex = 0;
            return;
        }

        var filePath = '${properties["RECORDED_SESSION_RETREIVAL_PATH"]}';
        filePath = filePath + sessionsToPlay[combinedSessionIndex] + ".mp4";
        combinedSessionIndex++;       
        audio.src = filePath;
        audio.play();
    }, false);
}
```

So, When a particular media file ends, it skips next media files and start playing next (after skipping 1,2) file. For each skipped media file, control comes in event listener, which shows that event listener is being call repeatedly while single call ends.

For the first Time I play audio file by this code:

```
  //PlayBack Session
function play(data) {

    //Just to deal with a scenario that when we play a combined session and in the mean while we start listening any other single
    //session, then after completion of this single session, remaining previous combined session should not resume.
    //console.log("Re-setting Player ...!!!");
    //$("#audio_files").val("");
    //sessionsToPlay = [];
    //combinedSessionIndex = 0;

    var filePath = '${properties["RECORDED_SESSION_RETREIVAL_PATH"]}';
    filePath = filePath + data + ".mp4";
    console.log("filePath: " + filePath);
    if (data == null || data == "") {
        alert("Nothing to Play ...!!!");
        return;
    }
    $("#playarea").attr({
        "src": filePath,
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    })
}
```

And after that when this ends, further clips are played using 'ended' event listener.

I am unable to find reason for this. Please guide me if I am doing anything wrong ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: If you change your event handler to have just one line of code that calls `console.log('ENDED event handled');` and remove all other code, do you still get multiple events? I am wondering if something you are doing inside the event handler is causing a new ended event, for example if an audio file was not found, or was incredibly short, or some other similar issue?

Comment: But the code for playing next media file will remain there ?

Comment: Take that out for now, because we want to test if you get multiple events without any of that code.

Comment: Actually, I am getting a very strange issue. When I refresh my page  and play then all media files play normally. Now, Again I press play button (Without refreshing page) the it plays media files by skipping one file. When it completes all files. Then Again if I press play button (Again without refreshing page) then it plays media files by skipping two files and so on ... Just for first time it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh My bad. I was registering the same Event Listener 'Ended' frequently (Each time user presses Play Button, while it should be just single time). That's why I was getting 'ended' events more than one time. It actually generates the 'Ended' event action for the number of times I register for 'Ended' event.

Do you not think it should consider just once ? Because our purpose is just getting notified when media file gets end. There's no logic of notifying multiple times though we register for multiple times.